# Count the occurrences of many elements in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's a piece of the dataset I'm working on :

```
{'type': {0: 'TV Show', 1: 'Movie', 2: 'Movie', 3: 'Movie', 4: 'Movie'},
 'title': {0: '3%', 1: '7:19', 2: '23:59', 3: '9', 4: '21'},
 'director': {0: nan,
  1: 'Jorge Michel Grau',
  2: 'Gilbert Chan',
  3: 'Shane Acker',
  4: 'Robert Luketic'},
 'cast': {0: 'João Miguel, Bianca Comparato, Michel Gomes, Rodolfo Valente, Vaneza Oliveira, Rafael Lozano, Viviane Porto, Mel Fronckowiak, Sergio Mamberti, Zezé Motta, Celso Frateschi',
  1: 'Demián Bichir, Héctor Bonilla, Oscar Serrano, Azalia Ortiz, Octavio Michel, Carmen Beato',
  2: 'Tedd Chan, Stella Chung, Henley Hii, Lawrence Koh, Tommy Kuan, Josh Lai, Mark Lee, Susan Leong, Benjamin Lim',
  3: 'Elijah Wood, John C. Reilly, Jennifer Connelly, Christopher Plummer, Crispin Glover, Martin Landau, Fred Tatasciore, Alan Oppenheimer, Tom Kane',
  4: 'Jim Sturgess, Kevin Spacey, Kate Bosworth, Aaron Yoo, Liza Lapira, Jacob Pitts, Laurence Fishburne, Jack McGee, Josh Gad, Sam Golzari, Helen Carey, Jack Gilpin'}}
```

What I'm trying to do is to extract the number of participations of each actor in a movie/tv-show. I created a couple of functions to separate the names of actors from the data :

```
def quick_extract(x) :
    z = re.split(',', x)
    for n, i in enumerate(z):
        z[n] = z[n].strip(' ')
    return z
def unique(data, column) :
    x = data[column].fillna('missing')
    s = []
    for l in x.apply(lambda z: quick_extract(z)) :
        s+=list(l)
    s = [i for i in s if len(i)>0] 
    return set(s)
unique(data, 'cast') # there are 32882 distinct actors in the dataset
```

In order to count the number of participations of actors, I used a for loop as follows :

```
for l in unique(data, 'cast') : 
    print(l, data['cast'].fillna('missing').apply(lambda z: l in z).sum())
```

But it just takes too much time since it iterates 32882 times. Iterative methods usually take a lot of time, is there any other efficient approach that could take less time in this case ?

Comment: I provided the `dict` so that anyone could copy it and just do `pd.DataFrame(dict)` to see it. As I said, all I'm trying to do is have the occurrences of the name of an actor in all movies/tv-shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire approach is very inefficient. Just use a `collections.Counter` object. Supposing you have a dataframe like:

```
In [8]: df
Out[8]:
      type  title           director                                               cast
0  TV Show     3%                NaN  João Miguel, Bianca Comparato, Michel Gomes, R...
1    Movie   7:19  Jorge Michel Grau  Demián Bichir, Héctor Bonilla, Oscar Serrano, ...
2    Movie  23:59       Gilbert Chan  Tedd Chan, Stella Chung, Henley Hii, Lawrence ...
3    Movie      9        Shane Acker  Elijah Wood, John C. Reilly, Jennifer Connelly...
4    Movie     21     Robert Luketic  Jim Sturgess, Kevin Spacey, Kate Bosworth, Aar...
```

Then you can just do something like:

```
In [9]: from collections import Counter

In [10]: Counter(
    ...:     actor.strip()
    ...:     for cast in df['cast'].fillna('missing')
    ...:     for actor in cast.split(',')
    ...: )
Out[10]:
Counter({'João Miguel': 1,
         'Bianca Comparato': 1,
         'Michel Gomes': 1,
         'Rodolfo Valente': 1,
         'Vaneza Oliveira': 1,
         'Rafael Lozano': 1,
         'Viviane Porto': 1,
         'Mel Fronckowiak': 1,
         'Sergio Mamberti': 1,
         'Zezé Motta': 1,
         'Celso Frateschi': 1,
         'Demián Bichir': 1,
         'Héctor Bonilla': 1,
         'Oscar Serrano': 1,
         'Azalia Ortiz': 1,
         'Octavio Michel': 1,
         'Carmen Beato': 1,
         'Tedd Chan': 1,
         'Stella Chung': 1,
         'Henley Hii': 1,
         'Lawrence Koh': 1,
         'Tommy Kuan': 1,
         'Josh Lai': 1,
         'Mark Lee': 1,
         'Susan Leong': 1,
         'Benjamin Lim': 1,
         'Elijah Wood': 1,
         'John C. Reilly': 1,
         'Jennifer Connelly': 1,
         'Christopher Plummer': 1,
         'Crispin Glover': 1,
         'Martin Landau': 1,
         'Fred Tatasciore': 1,
         'Alan Oppenheimer': 1,
         'Tom Kane': 1,
         'Jim Sturgess': 1,
         'Kevin Spacey': 1,
         'Kate Bosworth': 1,
         'Aaron Yoo': 1,
         'Liza Lapira': 1,
         'Jacob Pitts': 1,
         'Laurence Fishburne': 1,
         'Jack McGee': 1,
         'Josh Gad': 1,
         'Sam Golzari': 1,
         'Helen Carey': 1,
         'Jack Gilpin': 1})
```

Just to compare the two different approaches time-wise:

```
In [17]: %timeit df['cast'].str.split(', ').explode('cast').value_counts()
667 µs ± 16.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [18]: %%timeit
    ...: Counter(
    ...:     actor.strip()
    ...:     for cast in df['cast'].fillna('missing')
    ...:     for actor in cast.split(',')
    ...: )
    ...:
    ...:
146 µs ± 2.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Or perhaps a more fair comparison, without fillna and assuming you can split cleanly on a comma-and-space `', '`:

```
In [28]: %%timeit
    ...: Counter(
    ...:     actor
    ...:     for cast in df['cast']
    ...:     for actor in cast.split(', ')
    ...: )
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:
12.9 µs ± 543 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: wouldnt a split, explode, groupby do it? Interesting to see Counter solution used. Didn't know about it. Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @JoeFerndz You could do it that way, I woudl simplify your approach with just: `df['cast'].str.split(', ').explode('cast').value_counts()` but I bet the `Counter` approach is faster. Interesting to see a more complete dataset to get a good comparison

Answer (score 1):

You can explode and groupby to get the counts.

```
df['cast'] = df['cast'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))
df = df.explode('cast')
print (df.groupby('cast')['title'].count())
```

As @juanpa.arrivillaga stated, you can combine this to a single line:

```
print (df['cast'].str.split(', ').explode('cast').value_counts())
```

Full Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'type': {0: 'TV Show', 1: 'Movie', 2: 'Movie', 3: 'Movie', 4: 'Movie'},
 'title': {0: '3%', 1: '7:19', 2: '23:59', 3: '9', 4: '21'},
 'director': {0: np.nan,
  1: 'Jorge Michel Grau',
  2: 'Gilbert Chan',
  3: 'Shane Acker',
  4: 'Robert Luketic'},
 'cast': {0: 'João Miguel, Bianca Comparato, Michel Gomes, Rodolfo Valente, Vaneza Oliveira, Rafael Lozano, Viviane Porto, Mel Fronckowiak, Sergio Mamberti, Zezé Motta, Celso Frateschi',
  1: 'Demián Bichir, Héctor Bonilla, Oscar Serrano, Azalia Ortiz, Octavio Michel, Carmen Beato',
  2: 'Tedd Chan, Stella Chung, Henley Hii, Lawrence Koh, Tommy Kuan, Josh Lai, Mark Lee, Susan Leong, Benjamin Lim',
  3: 'Elijah Wood, John C. Reilly, Jennifer Connelly, Christopher Plummer, Crispin Glover, Martin Landau, Fred Tatasciore, Alan Oppenheimer, Tom Kane',
  4: 'Jim Sturgess, Kevin Spacey, Kate Bosworth, Aaron Yoo, Liza Lapira, Jacob Pitts, Laurence Fishburne, Jack McGee, Josh Gad, Sam Golzari, Helen Carey, Jack Gilpin'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['cast'] = df['cast'].apply(lambda x: x.split(', '))
df = df.explode('cast')
print (df.groupby('cast')['title'].count())
```

Output of this will be:

```
cast
Aaron Yoo              1
Alan Oppenheimer       1
Azalia Ortiz           1
Benjamin Lim           1
Bianca Comparato       1
Carmen Beato           1
Celso Frateschi        1
Christopher Plummer    1
Crispin Glover         1
Demián Bichir          1
Elijah Wood            1
Fred Tatasciore        1
Helen Carey            1
Henley Hii             1
Héctor Bonilla         1
Jack Gilpin            1
Jack McGee             1
Jacob Pitts            1
Jennifer Connelly      1
Jim Sturgess           1
John C. Reilly         1
Josh Gad               1
Josh Lai               1
João Miguel            1
Kate Bosworth          1
Kevin Spacey           1
Laurence Fishburne     1
Lawrence Koh           1
Liza Lapira            1
Mark Lee               1
Martin Landau          1
Mel Fronckowiak        1
Michel Gomes           1
Octavio Michel         1
Oscar Serrano          1
Rafael Lozano          1
Rodolfo Valente        1
Sam Golzari            1
Sergio Mamberti        1
Stella Chung           1
Susan Leong            1
Tedd Chan              1
Tom Kane               1
Tommy Kuan             1
Vaneza Oliveira        1
Viviane Porto          1
Zezé Motta             1
Name: title, dtype: int64
```